# What are the configurations required to use distcp from HA to Non HA cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I want to copy data from HA cluster to Non HA cluster using Distcp.
I am using following command for that purpose:

**hadoop distcp hdfs://nameserviceofHAcluster/apps/hive/warehouse/tabletobecopied hdfs://namenode2/apps/hive/warehouse/**

But it is giving following error:

```
17/08/11 06:53:56 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: namenode2
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:454)
```

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: namenode2
        ... 16 more

Comment: Do you run your command from HA or non-HA cluster?
Is "namenode2" a DNS name, a local entry in `/etc/hosts`? Is that server physically reachable on all HDFS ports? Are these clusters kerberized? If yes, do they use the same realm, or distinct realms with trust? If no, what user name are you using to run distcp, and does that user exist on the remote cluster? Come on, spit out some useful information!!

Comment: I am running this command On HA  cluster. namenode2 is DNS name. These clusters are not kerberized. I am using hdfs user.    I didn't understand what is physically reachable on all HDFS ports?

Comment: Ever heard about firewalls? These things that are blocking network traffic on unauthorized IP/port combinations, for security reasons?

Comment: Anyway `UnknownHostException` suggests that this is *not* a valid DNS name. Or at least, not valid for the specific DNS server that your specific machine uses. Did you try to `nslookup namenode2` ?

Comment: Yes I tried nslookup domainname on namenode of both the cluster and I am getting same server name and address on both the namenodes.

Comment: Also in my question I have not mentioned the exact hostname and nameservice. _nameserviceofHAcluster_ and _namenode2_  are dummy nameservice and hostname respectively.

Comment: And _namenode2_ is really running a NameNode service on default port 8020?? What happens when you simply run `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://namenode2/`apps?

Comment: Yes namenode2 has the namenode service running on default port  8020 and the ls command gives me the files and folder in that location

Comment: are you sure namenode2 is not a namespace? if it's in HA, it might be the namespace name not a valid resolvable domain.